# Insert R dataframe into SQL (RODBC) - error table not found

Tags: r, sql-server, dataframe, rodbc

I would like to drop my whole dataframe from R preferably using RODBC with `sqlSave` statement (not `sqlQuery`). Here is my sample code.

```
library(RODBC)
myconn <- odbcDriverConnect("some connection string")
mydf <- data.frame(col_1 = c(1,2,3), col_2 = c(2,3,4))
sqlSave(myconn, mydf, tablename = '[some_db].[some_schema].[my_table]',  append = F, rownames = F,  verbose=TRUE)
odbcClose(myconn)
```

After I execute it, I get back error message:

> Error in sqlColumns(channel, tablename) :
> ‘my_table’: table not found on channel

When I check in SQL Server, an empty table is present.

If I run the same code again, I get error message:

> Error in sqlSave(myconn, mydf, tablename = "[some_db].[some_schema].[my_table]",  :
> 42S01 2714 [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]There is already an object named 'my_table' in the database.
> [RODBC] ERROR: Could not SQLExecDirect 'CREATE TABLE [some_db].[some_schema].[my_table]  ("col_1" float, "col_2" float)'

Any suggestions on how to troubleshoot?

**UPDATE**

In SSMS I can run the following commands successfully:

```
CREATE TABLE [some_db].[some_schema].[my_table] (
    test int
);
drop table [some_db].[some_schema].[my_table]
```

Here are details of connection string:

```
Driver=ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server; Server=someserveraddress; Uid=user_login; Pwd=some_password
```

Comment: I'm not able to recreate the issue; this code works for me on my environment. Is it possible there's a permissions issue with the SQLServer database you're writing to? Perhaps try a different database or specify the database explicitly in the ODBC connection?

Comment: Would you like to save it to a certain schema within the database? Does it work if you run the SQL code directly?

Comment: @tester, yes, my full path is this `[some_db].[some_schema].[some_table]`. When I connect to SQL Server, I do not specify any db name. I am not sure what you mean by when I run code directly.

Comment: Whre do you specify the schema you want do write to? I'm asking because I had similar problems when trying to insert a table in our SQL database using `RPostgreSQL`. In the end I went for writing the table to `[some_db]` using `dbWriteTable` and then moving it to `[some_schema]` with an SQL query directly, because nothing else worked and it turned out that the driver was the issue. Hence, I'd try to check if it works using pure SQL first.

Comment: @tester, I updated my post to answer your question.

Comment: @tester `dbWriteTable` this is different package `odbc` and `DBI` if I remember correctly, I will try them as well.

Comment: I personnaly confirmed many times this [benchmark](https://github.com/r-dbi/odbc#benchmarks) : `DBI` is way faster than `RODBC`. Is there a specific reason why you would prefer `RODBC` to `DBI`?

Comment: @Waldi `RODBC` is usually easier to install.

Comment: @user1700890 can you specify the version of SQL Server you are using?

Comment: I see. However, installation is done once, whereas slowness in queries is every time you use it ;-)

Comment: @sgoley How can I find out SQL Server version I am guessing it is 2012.

Comment: You can run `SELECT @@VERSION` in SSMS.

Comment: @sgoley, Here is what your command returned: `Microsoft SQL Azure (RTM) - 12.0.2000.8   Oct  1 2020 18:48:35   Copyright (C) 2019 Microsoft Corporation `

Comment: This [seems related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23913616/rodbc-sqlsave-table-creation-problems)

Comment: could you share the connection string you use in `odbcDriverConnect`?

Comment: did you try to [remove the brackets](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44649996/13513328)?

Comment: @Waldi, I added connection string and yes, I tried removing brackets with the same result.

Comment: OK, thanks. The link above suggests to specify `database=` in connection string to avoid problems.  you can then call `sqlSave` without database in brackets. I don't know though how to specify schema. Perhaps first try without schema.

Comment: @Waldi, db in connection string and no brackets in schema and table worked! You can posted it as the answer and get the bounty. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To avoid the error, you could [specify the database in the connection string](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14423966/13513328):

```
Driver=ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server; Server = someserveraddress; database = some_db; Uid = user_login; Pwd = some_password
```

and [avoid using brackets](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44649996/13513328):

```
sqlSave(myconn, mydf, tablename = 'some_schema.my_table',  append = F, rownames = F,  verbose=TRUE)
```